# Get phoneNumbers and adresses from google people Api Node JS Passport Google o Auth Strategy

Tags: node.js, axios, passport.js, google-people-api, passport-google-oauth2

I'm building a NPM package to simplify passport logins.
At this time i'm implementing google o Auth 2 .0 Strategy and i want the function to login and register the user.

When the user Accepts the login and the scopes the idea is to gather some data extra besides the profile and email info.
For instance want the birthday, gender phone numbers etc.
So I've implemented a request using axios to the google People API. and I build the URL parsing the Google User ID and the access token granted by passport JS.
But when I do that i can retrieve gender, birthday, organization but i dont get addresses or phone numbers.

I ll try to post the code in ordered fashion so its more readable.
get route for the google auth with the scopes

```js
router.get("/goa",passport.authenticate("google",{
scope:[
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/directory.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.addresses.read"
]}))
```

**Strategy definition**
Here the strategy have two choices justLogin or loginAndRegister
the branch im working is the second one so ill provide the code of that function after the strategy definition
The loginAndRegister function is the verify function for passport js

```js
 function GoogleoAuth(authObject, loginOnly = false) {
    
            const { justLogin, loginAndregister } = oAuthModes(DAOgoa, DAOlocal, userNotFoundMessage);
            passport.use(new GoogleStrategy(Object.assign(Object.assign({}, authObject), { passReqToCallback: true, 
                scope: [
                    "openid",
                    "profile",
                    "email",
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts",
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read",
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read",
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.addresses.read",
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read",
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.organization.read",
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/directory.readonly",
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly"

                ] }), (loginOnly) ? justLogin : loginAndregister));
            passport.serializeUser((user, done) => __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
                done(null, yield user._id);
            }));
            passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
                if (loginOnly) {
                    DAOlocal.findById(id, done);
                }
                else {
                    DAOgoa.findById(id, done);
                }
            });
            return this;
}
```

**loginAndRegister verify function**

```js
const loginAndregister = (req, accessToken, _refreshToken, _profile, email, cb) => __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
        const authorizationObject = {
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read": "birthdays",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read": "phoneNumbers",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.addresses.read": "addresses",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read": "genders",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.organization.read": "organizations",
            "openid": "",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile": "",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email": "",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts":"",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly":"",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/directory.readonly":""
        };
        let urlFields = "";
        const tokenInfo = yield axios_1.default.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=${accessToken}`);
        if ("data" in tokenInfo)
            if ("scope" in tokenInfo.data) {
                console.log("scopes exists");
                tokenInfo.data.scope.split(" ").forEach((scope) => {
                    if (authorizationObject[scope] !== "")
                        urlFields += authorizationObject[scope] + ",";
                });
                urlFields = urlFields.substring(0, urlFields.length);
            }
        console.log(urlFields);
        const extendedData = yield axios_1.default.get(`https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/${email.id}?personFields=${urlFields}&access_token=${accessToken}`);
        console.log(extendedData.data, Object.keys(extendedData.data),accessToken);
        try {
            const resultado = yield DAOgoa.findByUserName(email.emails[0].value);
            loggerHLP_1.loggerObject.debug.debug({ level: "debug", method: "Login and Register GoogleoAuth", data: resultado });
            if (resultado) {
                return cb(null, resultado);
            }
            try {
                const usercreated = yield DAOgoa.createUser({ username: email.emails[0].value, password: email.id, name: email.name.givenName, lastname: email.name.familyName, avatar: email.photos[0].value });
                return cb(null, usercreated);
            }
            catch (err) {
                loggerHLP_1.loggerObject.error.error({ level: "error", method: "Login and Register GoogleoAuth", message: err });
                return cb(err, null, { message: "Error creating user" });
            }
        }
        catch (err) {
            loggerHLP_1.loggerObject.error.error({ level: "error", method: "Login and Register GoogleoAuth", message: err });
            return cb(err, null, { message: "Error login with oAuth" });
        }
    })
```

And in the google dev console ive this permissions set for my app:

```
.../auth/contacts   
.../auth/contacts.readonly  
.../auth/directory.readonly 
openid  
People API  .../auth/user.addresses.read    
People API  .../auth/user.birthday.read
People API  .../auth/user.phonenumbers.read
People API  .../auth/userinfo.email
People API  .../auth/userinfo.profile
```

So I dont understand why it doesn't give me phone numbers and addresses but it gives me the rest of the resources i ask.
At this time I'm only trying to get the thata to the

```js
console.log(extendedData.data, Object.keys(extendedData.data),accessToken);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API will only return `phoneNumber` and `addresses` if they were added in the user's profile under `Contact info` at https://aboutme.google.com, it will not return the data at https://myaccount.google.com/personal-info as that is considered ["Recovery information"](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/183723?hl=en&ref_topic=3382296#zippy=%2Cadd-a-recovery-phone-number).

More context at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78151501

Comment: Thanks for the answer , so there is no way to así for the user Phone through google apis?

Comment: Your code will work but only if the user has added their phone number to their public information under "Contact info" at https://myaccount.google.com/profile: https://i.imgur.com/6dmWLUE.png. Apparently this was mostly used in Google+ days so it is not very common for a Google Account user to add their phone number or address there anymore.